# Adding additional disks to ubuntu 20 installation

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, postgresql, storage

i have a dedicated server with 2x 1.92 TB NVMe SSD

In this server i want it to hold a lot of data terabites worth of data. I have 24 CPUs so it has the processing power and 128GB of memory.

In future i want to add several 12TB HDD disks to accommodate the growing amounts of data. I am using postgresql to store my data. How do i go about making the additional storage available to postgresql so that it can use additional storage that i am adding.

Thanks.

Comment: Adding storage to Ubuntu is not a problem. It is more about `postgresql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux you can set up LVM (Logical Volume Manager) to logically expand your partitions over several HDDs, then it is just a question of adding a HDD and register it via LVM, then extend your partition to include the new HDD. You can also use table partitioning, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-partitioning.html, but I would personally use the LVM alternative. See e.g.: https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-increase-an-lvm-partition/